# res.json not returning array member (SIMPLE LOGIN CODE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, server

So I am doing a simple login program and I am checking to see if the input email matches a stored email in an array I defined  in the code. But when I command `res.json(User[0].email)` to see the value of the email in the array, it returns nothing. As a result, I am unable to compare the the two emails.

This is odd because if I ask for the array `itself(res.json(User))` it gives me the full array no problem. Can someone help me find the issue.

Here is the code below :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
var User = [{
    email: "t@hotmail.com",
    password: "456"
}, {
    email: "g@hotmail.com",
    password: "vvv"
}, {
    email: "p@hotmail.com",
    password: "vvv"
}]


// Get request for registration
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('index.ejs');
})

//get request for User Profile
app.get('/welcome', (req, res) => {
    res.render('welcome.ejs')
})

//get request for Login
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {

    res.render('login.ejs');
})


// Post request on registration
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    NewUser = [{
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }]
    User.push(NewUser);

    res.redirect('/login')

})

//Post request on Login page
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    res.json(User[3].email)
})


app.listen(PORT)
```

Register html

```
<h1> Registration page</h1>


<form type ="/" method="POST" >


<div class="div">
<label name="email" for ="password"> Enter email </label>
<input name="email" type="email" required> 
</div> 
 <div class="div">
<label name="password" for="password"> Enter password </label>
<input name="password" type="password"  required> 
</div> 
<div>
<button> Register</button>

</div>

<a href="/login">Login</a>



</form>
```

Login html

```
<h1> Login page</h1>


<form type ="/login" method="POST" >


<div class="div">
<label name="email" for ="password"> Enter email </label>
<input name="email" type="email" required> 
</div> 
 <div class="div">
<label name="password" for="password"> Enter password </label>
<input name="password" type="password"  required> 
</div> 
<div>
<button> Login</button>

</div>

<a href="/">Register</a>



</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get `User[3].email` (which doesn't initially exist) with a POST request? Is that the code you are asking about (because you said you were asking for `0` before). Are you actually making a POST request to that URL?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,  You are technically right. But in my case User[3] would exist i  because I come from the register page and tack on a new user and email to the array before going to the login page.

Comment: Are you actually making a POST request to that URL?

Comment: Yes, I am making a POST on the URL . If I go from registration page (after I enter a new email and password)-> login page, and I  type in res,json (User), I get all the users in the code array PLUS the new user as the 4th element in the array.

Comment: Where are you typing `res,json (User)`?

Comment: AT the bottom of the code . So instead of json(User[3].email) I would type in res.json(User) . I do this to verify that the user I registered in the registration page  is actually in the array before doing any operations. It shows any new user from the register page is there. But won't let me access that new user if I use res.json(User[3]) or res.json(User[3].email) it will work for other numbers (0,1 or 2) but not 3 (despite showing 4 members when I type res,json(User). I will add the login and register htmls to main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you can access the first three [0,1,2] elements of the array, but can't access the newly added element.

```
NewUser = [{
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
}]
User.push(NewUser);
```

Here, in this part of the code, you are pushing an array `NewUser` into your `User` array.
After this operation, your `User` array will look like this:

```
[
    {
        email: "t@hotmail.com",
        password: "456"
    }, 
    {
        email: "g@hotmail.com",
        password: "vvv"
    }, 
    {
        email: "p@hotmail.com",
        password: "vvv"
    },
    [
        {
            email: value from req.body.email,
            password: value from req.body.password
        }
    ]
]
```

The last element of your `User` array is an array itself.

The solution to this is to simply push an object into your `User` array like this:

```
NewUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
}
User.push(NewUser);
```

Comment: THANKS! ,I REALLY  appreciate you going through the whole code to find the issue.